# What, if any, is the tolerance built into speed limits in India?

Tags: india, speeding

Jurisdiction: India
Legislation: Central Motor Vehicles Act

Sub-jurisdiction: Maharashtra
Legislation: Mumbai Motor Vehicles Act

Speed limits in India are according to the referenced article below. In many nations, there is actually a grace of +5km/hr, or similar value so that any inadvertent gain (e.g. slope of carriageway, downwind) does not result in a fine.

Is there any similar grace/speed tolerance in India?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limits_in_India

Comment: In most jurisdictions the grace isn't in the law but in the quality of the measurement device - radar guns in Germany have 10% or 4 km/h tolerance (the greater of the two) while a laser fence has less than 1 km/h tolerance.

Comment: Usually, the discretion isn't stated in a statue and is instead a matter of law enforcement practice.

Comment: I think legally there is zero tolerance in Germany, but the fact that a radar gun showed you driving at 53 km/h isn't enough evidence to show that you exceeded the 50 km/h speed limit. A radar gun showing you driving at 56 km/h is taken as proof that you drove at at least 51 km/h (you might have been driving at 62 km/h).

Comment: And the grace can change over time.  In NZ, they used to reduce the 5K during holiday times, supposedly to make it safer.

Comment: There is also the question whether they want to prosecute you. German police tends to put up speed limits _below_ the highest safe speed, so that the average not quite law abiding driver may exceed the speed limit, but still be at a safe speed. It's likely that you will be prosecuted if you are above the safe speed. It would be different in places where speeding tickets are seen as a source of income to the state or the police.

Answer (score 4):

**What, if any, is the tolerance built into speed limits in India?**

None in statute (that I can find), but the police may have an informal policy<sup>1</sup>
to allow for other factors like inaccuracies in one's speedometer and misreading the needle due to [parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax).

---

<sup>1</sup>The one I am aware of is "*10% +2*" where, say, anyone going over 35mph on a 30mph road gets a ticket etc

Comment: Also could have policies to account for tolerance in the tools used to detect vehicle speed